# Contraction Mapping Theorem proof of uniqueness and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

The Contraction Mapping Theorem states the following:

[Quoting from the book: "An Introduction to Numerical Analysis" by Suli and Mayers]

Let $g$ be a real-valued function, defined and continuous on a bounded closed interval $[a,b]$ of the real line, and assume that $g(x)\in[a,b]$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Suppose, further, that $g$ is a contraction on $[a,b]$. Then, $g$ has a unique fixed point $\xi$ in the interval $[a,b].$ Moreover, the sequence $(x_k)$ defined by $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$ for $k=0,1,2,...,$, converges to $\xi$ as $k\to\infty$ for any starting value $x_0$ in $[a,b].$

I've been able to prove the existence of a fixed-point $\xi$ as it is a consequence of Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem. However, I'm unable to prove 1) the uniqueness of $\xi$ in the interval $[a,b].$; and 2) that the sequence $(x_k)$ converges to $\xi$ as $k\to\infty$ for any starting value $x_0$ in $[a,b].$

Answer (score 0):

The function $g$ is a contraction mapping if there exists a $k\in (0,1)$, such that
$$
|g(x)-g(y)|\le k|x-y|,
$$
for all $x,y\in[a,b]$.

Then
$$
|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|g(x_n)-g(x_{n-1})|\le k |x_n-x_{n-1}|
$$
and inductively
$$
|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le k |x_n-x_{n-1}|\le \cdots\le k^n |x_1-x_0|
$$
In particular,
$$
|x_{m}-x_n|\le |x_{m}-x_{m-1}|+\cdots+|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le (k^{m-1}+\cdots+k^{n-1})|x_1-x_0|
\le |x_1-x_0|\sum_{j=n-1}^\infty k^j=\frac{k^{n-1}}{1-k}|x_1-x_0|,
$$
and hence $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and thus convergent.

If $x_n\to x$, then $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)\to g(x)$, and thus $g(x)=x$.

Comment: Is that sufficient to prove that it is Cauchy? shouldn't there be an $\epsilon >0$ or all values n,m greater than N?